# How can I add a new value to my text editcontroller in Text formfield?

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

I have a database and retrieving my Data from firestore.

```
class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  UserModel userModel;
  List<UserModel> userModelList = [];
  Future<void> getUserData() async {
    List<UserModel> newList = [];
    User currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    QuerySnapshot userSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Manufacturer-Accounts")
        .get();

    userSnapshot.docs.forEach(
      (element) {
        if (currentUser.uid == element.data()['Manufacturer_ID']) {
          userModel = UserModel(
            userFName: element.data()['FirstName'],
            userCompany: element.data()['Company'],
            userDesignation: element.data()['Designation'],
            userEmail: element.data()['Email'],
            userPhone: element.data()['PhoneNumber'],
            userLastName: element.data()['LastName'],
          );
          newList.add(userModel);
        }
        userModelList = newList;
      },
    );
  }
```

I have retrieved my data as a list and set it to the textformfield like this in a stateful widget as I know the TextEditing Controller should be initiated in stateful widget and should not be as final.

```
class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = "/Settings";

  @override
  _ProfileScreenState createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  File _pickedImageFile;
  PickedFile _pickedImage;
  TextEditingController firstName;
  TextEditingController lastName;
  TextEditingController phoneNumber;
  TextEditingController designation;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  void userDetailsUpdate() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Manufacturer-Accounts")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .update({
      'Designation': designation.text,
      'FirstName': firstName.text,
      'LastName': lastName.text,
      //'Email': user.email,
      'Phone': phoneNumber.text,
      //'UserImage': imageUrl == null ? "" : imageUrl,
    });
  }

  Future<void> getImage({ImageSource source}) async {
    _pickedImage = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: source);
    if (_pickedImage != null) {
      _pickedImageFile = File(_pickedImage.path);
    }
  }

  String imageUrl;
  void _uploadImage({File image}) async {
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('UserImage')
        .child("UserImage/${user.uid}");
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(image);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    imageUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  }

  Future<void> myDiscardChanges() {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return CupertinoAlertDialog(
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: [
                Text("Discard changes?"),
                SizedBox(height: 12),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    FlatButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      color: Colors.amber[400],
                      hoverColor: Colors.blueGrey[300],
                      child: Text("Yes"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          editProfile = false;
                        });
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      color: Colors.amber[400],
                      hoverColor: Colors.blueGrey[300],
                      child: Text("No"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          editProfile = true;
                        });
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> myDialogBox() {
    return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListBody(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                    title: Text("Camera"),
                    onTap: () {
                      getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                    title: Text("Gallery"),
                    onTap: () {
                      getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  bool editProfile = false;
  ProductProvider productProvider;
  Widget newBuildTrue() {
    List<UserModel> userModel = productProvider.getUserModelList;
    return Column(
      children: userModel.map((e) {
        //userImage = e.userImage;
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "First Name",
                endText: e.userFName,
              ),
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "Last Name",
                endText: e.userLastName,
              ),
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "E-mail",
                endText: e.userEmail,
              ),
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "Designation",
                endText: e.userDesignation,
              ),
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "Company",
                endText: e.userCompany,
              ),
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "Telephone No",
                endText: (e.userPhone).toString(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

  String userImage;
  Widget newBuildFalse() {
    List<UserModel> userModel = productProvider.getUserModelList;
    return Column(
      children: userModel.map((e) {
        //userImage = e.userImage;
        firstName = TextEditingController(text: e.userFName);
        lastName = TextEditingController(text: e.userLastName);
        phoneNumber = TextEditingController(text: e.userPhone);
        designation = TextEditingController(text: e.userDesignation);
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // buildTextFormField(editText: "FirstName"),
              MyTextFormField(
                name: "FirstName",
                controller: firstName,
              ),
              MyTextFormField(
                name: "LastName",
                controller: lastName,
              ),

              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "E-mail",
                endText: e.userEmail,
              ),
              MyTextFormField(
                name: "Designation",
                controller: designation,
              ),
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "Company",
                endText: e.userCompany,
              ),
              MyTextFormField(
                name: "Telephone No",
                controller: phoneNumber,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //firstName.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context);
    productProvider.getUserData();
    ScreenUtil.init(context, height: 896, width: 414, allowFontScaling: true);
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: editProfile == false
            ? IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                color: kPrimaryColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => MenuFrame(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              )
            : Container(),
        elevation: 1,
        actions: [
          editProfile == false
              ? IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      editProfile = true;
                    });
                  },
                )
              : IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                  onPressed: () {
                    myDiscardChanges();
                  },
                ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    height: kSpacingUnit.w * 10,
                    width: kSpacingUnit.w * 10,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: kSpacingUnit.w * 3),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: kSpacingUnit.w * 8,
                          backgroundImage: _pickedImageFile == null
                              ? AssetImage('assets/images/12.jpg')
                              : FileImage(_pickedImageFile),
                        ),
                        editProfile == true
                            ? Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                child: Container(
                                  height: kSpacingUnit.w * 2.5,
                                  width: kSpacingUnit.w * 2.5,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: kAccentColor,
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    heightFactor: kSpacingUnit.w * 1.5,
                                    widthFactor: kSpacingUnit.w * 1.5,
                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        myDialogBox();
                                      },
                                      child: Icon(
                                        LineAwesomeIcons.pen,
                                        color: kDarkPrimaryColor,
                                        size: ScreenUtil()
                                            .setSp(kSpacingUnit.w * 1.5),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            : Container(),
                      ],
                    )),
                SizedBox(height: kSpacingUnit.w * 1.5),
                editProfile == false ? newBuildTrue() : newBuildFalse(),
                editProfile == true
                    ? FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        height: 50,
                        minWidth: 400,
                        child: Text("Save"),
                        onPressed: () {
                          userDetailsUpdate();
                          //_uploadImage(image: _pickedImageFile);
                          setState(() {
                            editProfile = false;
                          });
                        },
                      )
                    : Container(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildContainerTrue({String startText, String endText}) {
    return Container(
      height: kSpacingUnit.w * 5.5,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: kSpacingUnit.w * 2,
      ).copyWith(
        bottom: kSpacingUnit.w * 2,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: kSpacingUnit.w * 1.5,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(kSpacingUnit.w * 3),
        color: kDarkSecondaryColor,
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            width: 100,
            height: kSpacingUnit.w * 5.5,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              // color: Colors.green,
              border: Border(
                right: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1),
              ),
            ),
            child: Text(
              startText,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: kSpacingUnit.w * 1.5),
          Text(
            endText,
            style: kTitleTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              color: Colors.amber,
              fontSize: 12,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

But still following the procedures I am facing an issue like when I enter my new value to the controller it still shows a new value when my keyboard exit. Tried lot of ways and still having the same issue.

Comment: I did not understand your explanation of the problem. (last paragraph)

Comment: If your problem is that the value of your textfield is returning to its original value, note that in the construction of your table, your textfield controllers gain their original value again. So the original value will always be loaded when you hear an update to the table widget.

Comment: I need to insert a new value to my controller as an initial value it should show the values from firestore collection when I enter a new value it should show the new entered text. But in my situation when I try to close my keyboard it automatically returns to the value which was initiated

Comment: Yes thats the issue which i am currently facing what is the suitable way of doing it then?

Comment: Just with the code shown, I can't give you an answer. The idea is that newBuildFalse () is called only when you load the data. Something is causing him to be called more often.

Comment: Ok Ill look into that and let you know thanks

Comment: I have uploaded my full code here

Comment: The problems in your code, especially in newBuildFalse. You have a list of UserModel and you use that list to create containers with textformfields. But you will have several textformfields for the same field and only one controller. What I mean, if you have 3 usermodels in the list, you will have 3 textformfield for the firstname, but you will only have one firstName controller. You must have a controller for each textformfield, for that you would have to use an array of TextEditingController.

Comment: The second problem, you are updating the controllers inside the widget, that is, every time you do a setstate, The original data is loaded again to the controllers. You should only request the data once and update the information in the controllers. This should normally be done in initstate. Thus, when you do a setstate, the original data is not updated again.

Comment: If your logic is intended to update the data, save it to the firebase and load it up to date, then that's not a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions I was able to figure it out. It was the error with my newBuildFalse. The issue was I need to have to set the controllers in my newBuildTrue not in newBuildFalse. I'll add my answer here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making changes to my functions it actually worked.

```
Widget newBuildTrue() {
    List<UserModel> userModel = productProvider.getUserModelList;
    return Column(
      children: userModel.map((e) {
        firstName = TextEditingController(text: e.userFName);
        lastName = TextEditingController(text: e.userLastName);
        phoneNumber = TextEditingController(text: e.userPhone);
        designation = TextEditingController(text: e.userDesignation);
        //userImage = e.userImage;
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "First Name",
                endText: e.userFName,
              ),
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "Last Name",
                endText: e.userLastName,
              ),
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "E-mail",
                endText: e.userEmail,
              ),
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "Designation",
                endText: e.userDesignation,
              ),
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "Company",
                endText: e.userCompany,
              ),
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "Telephone No",
                endText: (e.userPhone).toString(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

  String userImage;
  Widget newBuildFalse() {
    List<UserModel> userModel = productProvider.getUserModelList;
    return Column(
      children: userModel.map((e) {
        //userImage = e.userImage;

        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // buildTextFormField(editText: "FirstName"),
              MyTextFormField(
                name: "FirstName",
                controller: firstName,
              ),
              buildTextFormField(
                editText: "LastName",
                textEditingController: lastName,
              ),

              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "E-mail",
                endText: e.userEmail,
              ),
              MyTextFormField(
                name: "Designation",
                controller: designation,
              ),
              buildContainerTrue(
                startText: "Company",
                endText: e.userCompany,
              ),
              MyTextFormField(
                name: "Telephone No",
                controller: phoneNumber,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You still have one controller to many text fields, make a test with two itens in userModel list.

Comment: Actually I did, It works perfectly. Now I am  having error with only the imageurl update. At start it worked properly now it is breaking at await uploadTask.onComplete. I have degraded my firestore storage to 4.0.1. Is it because of the downgrading?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65107991/how-to-save-the-image-to-firebase-storage-and-save-the-url-to-firebase-firestore Claudio Castro would be great if you could help me with this too